# Premiere Pro Hardware vs Software Encoding - Quality results

Tags: video, encoding, adobe-premiere

While exporting a Video in Adobe Premiere Pro, there is the option to export a Video with Software or Hardware Accelerated encoder. After i searched a bit about this topic i found that it is pretty unclear if the Hardware Encoding will result in lower quality of the video, also the official site of adobe itself won't give any information on this. My question is, will hardware encoding in premiere pro result in a lower quality as trade for rendering time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend asking question on https://video.stackexchange.com, but yes, quality is definitively inferior (at times unusable) when using hardware encoding.

I am very disappointed as render times are very appealing when using hardware encoding.

FYI, I am using Adobe Premiere 22.4 on macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the quality will be lower.

This is because a software-based encoder can use many more algorithms that are "simulated" on the CPU, the hardware encoder may be much faster because the algorithms are physical circuits on a chip. But having algorithms on a chip with limited space means there's only so many options a hardware encoder can use, whereas the software encoder can use as many options as it wants.

Different software encoders all following the same standard can be better or worse than each other because the algorithms they use to compress are different. For example, libaom-av1 and svt-av1 both encode to av1, but differ greatly in speed, quality and size.

For example, software encoding is like using an ever-improving piece of software, which is slow because it's simulated but high quality because it's complex, versus hardware encoding, which is a physical chip that can't change but is fast and lower quality because it's simpler.

If you don't care about file size, I suggest bumping up the bitrate a lot and just hardware encoding. But if it's for web content, which is gonna get re-encoded again and again, you might not wanna make the first encode in that chain a hardware encode.